# Is there a way to get column names using hiveContext?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an "iplRDD" which is a json, and I do below steps and query through hivecontext. I get the results but without columns headers. Is there is a way to get the columns names along with the values?

```
val teamRDD = hiveContext.jsonRDD(iplRDD) 
teamRDD.registerTempTable("teams") 
hiveContext.cacheTable("teams") 

val result = hiveContext.sql("select * from teams where  team_name = "KKR" ) 
result.collect.foreach(println)
```

Any thoughts please ?

Answer (score 2):

`teamRDD.schema.fieldNames` should contain the header names.

Answer (score 1):

you can save your dataframe 'result' like this with header as csv file:

```
result.write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(outputPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using:

```
result.schema().fields();
```